# Unable to iframe WSGI Web App in Apache Superset

Tags: python, plotly-dash, apache-superset

Former colleagues developped an internal graphical tool to view data with Apache Superset and a WSGI App based on Dash. These former colleagues are no longer here (of course).
So basically, they developped this tool based on Dash because Superset didn't fit what they had in mind.

We actually have a problem on Superset when we try to embed our Dash app in a HTML iframe. There's nothing showing on Superset. But iframe actually works when I create a simple HTML file calling the web page.

Apache Superset and the Dash app are both behind NGINX for HTTPS redirection.
Here all the required configurations/codes below so you might be able to help me with this case.

## Apache Superset

superset_config.py (without Secret Key, SQL URI and Servers Informations) :

```
DISPLAY_MAX_ROW = 1000
ROW_LIMIT = 1000000
SQL_MAX_ROW = 1000000

# Flask-WTF flag for CSRF
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
# Add endpoints that need to be exempt from CSRF protection
WTF_CSRF_EXEMPT_LIST = []
# A CSRF token that expires in 1 year
WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365

# Set this API key to enable Mapbox visualizations
MAPBOX_API_KEY = ''

FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "ALERT_REPORTS": True,
    "DASHBOARD_CROSS_FILTERS": True,
    "DASHBOARD_FILTERS_EXPERIMENTAL": True,
    "DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS_SET": True,
    "DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS": True,
    "DASHBOARD_RBAC": True,
    "DYNAMIC_PLUGINS": True,
    "ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING": True
}

ENABLE_CORS = True
CORS_OPTIONS = {
    'allow_headers': ['*'],
    'origins': ['*'],
    'resources': ['*']
}

EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 86400,
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
}

FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 86400,
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
}

TALISMAN_ENABLED = True
TALISMAN_CONFIG = {
    "content_security_policy": {
        "img-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:"
        ],
        "connect-src": [
            "'self'",
            "https://api.mapbox.com",
            "https://events.mapbox.com",
        ],
        "style-src": [
            "'self'",
            "'unsafe-inline'"
        ],
        "frame-ancestors": [
            "'self'"
        ]
    },
    "content_security_policy_nonce_in": [
        "script-src"
    ],
    "force_https": True
}
```

NGINX for Superset (hidding Certs Informations and Server Informations) :

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

## Dash WSGI

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import apps
import os
import pkgutil
import re

superset_colors = {"blue" : "rgb(32,167,201)"}

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True, title = "IMEDA")

server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])

@callback(Output('page-content', 'children'), Input('url', 'pathname'))

def display_page(pathname):
    address = re.search(r"/apps/(.*)", pathname)
    modules = [a.name  for a in pkgutil.iter_modules(apps.__path__)]

    if address is not None:
        dashboard = address.group(1)

    if address is None or dashboard not in modules:
        return '404'
    else:
        return getattr(apps, dashboard).layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

NGINX for Dash WSGI :

```
server {
        listen 8443 ssl;
        listen [::]:8443 ssl;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

I hope you guys could help me to find the solution to this problem.

I tried these following steps

- I tried to play with CSP settings in superset_config.py and app.py
- I tried to play with HTTP Headers in NGINX for both Superset and Dash
- I create HTML file calling iframe : this works perfectly from my computer